# Remove non alphanumeric character from beginning and ending

Tags: java

"When fetching a string from a database table, it may appear as follows:

ex. **#$%^&*\n\r\t** company; name; xyz; abc; pqr; **\t\r@#$()-.**
In the example above, the string starts and ends with non-alphanumeric characters. I want to remove all non-alphanumeric characters from the beginning and end of the given string, resulting in: company; name; xyz; abc; pqr;"

Comment: And what went wrong with your attempt? Edit it into the question please.

Comment: I hope you're asking this because you want to use any solution you learn here to help you clean up your database.  If not, you're solving the wrong problem, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like that:

```
    String example="#$%^&*\n\r\t company; name; xyz; abc; pqr; \t\r@#$()-";
    String result = example.replaceAll("(^[^\\w;]+|[^\\w;]+$)", "");
    System.out.println(result);
```

It prints:

> company; name; xyz; abc; pqr;

It can be replaced with two replaces - for the start of string and then for the end like that:

```
   String result=example.replaceAll("^[^\\w;]+", "").replaceAll("[^\\w;]+$", ""));
```

Comment: What about `"(^\\W*|\\W*$)"`, with just one replaceAll

Comment: That's true ;) It would still need to be a group though because from the required answer it seems that semicolons should also remain

Comment: I think you also want to remove the space at the end / start of the replaced sequence

Comment: In this case you can use `"(^\\W*|[^\\w;]*$)"` +1 any way

Comment: Hi @Lino with my regex you can solve the spaces problem in one shot

Comment: I agree that is easier.

Comment: thanks that is easier way

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to regex is just to iterate over the chars of the string and then find out the start and end indices of the first respectively last encountered alpha numeric value:

```
public static String trim(String input) {
    int length = input.length(), start = 0, end = length;

    // iterate from the start
    // until the first alphanumeric char is encountered
    while (start < length && notAlphaNumeric(input.charAt(start++))) {}
    start--;

    // iterate from the end
    // until the first alphanumeric char is encountered
    while (0 < end && notAlphaNumeric(input.charAt(--end))) {}
    end++;

    // return the original string if nothing has changed
    if (start == 0 && end == length) return input;

    // return an empty string if the indices passed one another
    if (start >= end) return "";

    // else return the substring from start to end
    return input.substring(start, end);
}

private static boolean notAlphaNumeric(char c) {
    return c != ';' && (c < '0' || c > '9') && (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') && (c < 'a' || c > 'z');
}
```

The values I defined as *alphanumeric* match this regex group: `[;0-9a-zA-Z]`